# react hooks: Pass a state setter as an argument to an onChange function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, optimization, jsx

> I already implement that. It works! but could it be expensive ?? if it
> is then how?

```
const [neighbourCountryGeneraleDes, setNeighbourCountryGeneralDes] = useState(neighbour_country_generale_des_init);
const [neighbouringProvincePopulationSummary, setNeighbouringProvincePopulationSummary] = useState(neighbouring_province_population_summary_init);

const onChangeInput = (e, data, setData) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
};
```

JSX

```
<div style={{ marginBottom: "15px" }}>
  <SearchInputField
    width="785px"
    headText="বন্দরের নাম"
    icon={inputIcon}
    bool={false}
    placeholder="বন্দরের নাম লিখুন"
    name="air_port_name"
    value={neighbourCountryGeneraleDes.air_port_name}
    handleChange={(e) => onChangeInput(e, neighbourCountryGeneraleDes,setNeighbourCountryGeneralDes)}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Why you want to do that? Is the state setter not in your current scope?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. No, it's not expensive. It's nice and functional and allows you to move your `onChangeInput` function wherever you want.

Comment: Incidentally, your `onChangeInput` function isn't a React Hook, it's a plain function.

Comment: Matthias Wiedemann - I have a big form with lot of complex form state i want use a generic onChange function for all of inputs

Comment: Will- There is a lot of lagging issue when i wrote something in those input fields. u sure its not expensive?